# Kafka Partition+Spark Streaming Context

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Scenario-I have 1 topic with 2 partitions with different data set collections say A,B.I am aware that the the dstream can consume the messages at the partition level and the topic level.
Query-Can we use two different streaming contexts for the each partition or a single streaming context for the entire topic and later filter the partition level data?I am concerned about the performance on increasing the no of streaming contexts.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot have more than one Spark Context

Comment: If you are using Spark Streaming(Receiver less). It should handle this.

Comment: As you will receive each Kafka partition as a separate RDD partition, there is nothing to worry about. Spark handles this beautifully. All you need to do is write appropriate logic for each partition (based on some identifier for each of the types you have).

Comment: If I had to do different logic in spark for each partition,Is there any way I can select the particular partition A without actually using filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the documentation.

> Simplified Parallelism: No need to create multiple input Kafka streams
>   and union them. With directStream, Spark Streaming will create as many
>   RDD partitions as there are Kafka partitions to consume, which will
>   all read data from Kafka in parallel. So there is a one-to-one mapping
>   between Kafka and RDD partitions, which is easier to understand and
>   tune.

Therefore, if you are using Direct Stream based Spark Streaming consumer it should handle the parallelism.

Comment: Thanks much!!Could you please help me with the documentation link

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html

Comment: Can we achieve parallel reading of partitions with this feature of spark streaming?